# Base R split() function causing "error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax)

Tags: r

I am working with `tidycensus` and `segregation` to do an analysis.

To create my data, I am running this:

```
library(tidycensus)
library(tidyverse)
library(segregation)
library(tigris)
library(sf)

los.angeles.indices <- get_acs(
  geography = "tract",
  variables = c(
    white = "B03002_003",
    black = "B03002_004",
    hispanic = "B03002_012"
  ), 
  state = "CA",
  geometry = TRUE,
  year = 2012
) 

california.cities <- get_acs(
  geography = "place",
  state = "CA",
  variables = "B01001_001",
  geometry = TRUE,
  year = 2012,
  survey = "acs1"
) %>%
  filter(estimate >= 100000) %>%
  transmute(urban_name = str_remove(NAME, 
                                    fixed(" city, California")))

ca_city_data <- los.angeles.indices %>%
  st_join(california.cities, left = FALSE) %>%
  select(-NAME) %>%
  st_drop_geometry()
```

After, I am attempting to run this:

```
inglewood_entropy <- ca_city_data %>%
  filter(urban_name == "Inglewood") %>%
  split(~GEOID) %>%
  map_dbl(~{
    entropy(
      data = .x,
      group = "variable",
      weight = "estimate",
      base = 4
    )
  }) %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "GEOID") %>%
  rename(entropy = value)
```

Unfortunately, it is causing this error:

```
Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors
```

The end result *should* look something like this:

```
inglewood_entropy
#> # A tibble: 50 × 2
#>    GEOID       entropy
#>    <chr>         <dbl>
#>  1 06037234902   0.576
#>  2 06037235100   0.453
#>  3 06037235201   0.548
#>  4 06037235202   0.550
#>  5 06037237900   0.357
#>  6 06037238000   0.420
#>  7 06037238100   0.421
#>  8 06037238400   0.430
#>  9 06037276100   0.590
#> 10 06037277100   0.506
#> # … with 40 more rows
```

What is really strange is that I asked the creator of the `segregation` package about the issue and he was able to run the code perfectly fine!

You can see our short discussion here where it works for him: [Segregation GitHub Issue](https://github.com/elbersb/segregation/issues/8)

I am pretty sure the issue is with the `split(~GEOID)` part of the code, but I am not sure.

Regardless, I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out why this is not working for me but worked perfectly fine when I asked the creator of the package. And, since this is not an issue with the package, I'd rather not pester him about it.

So, in short: **any ideas on how to run the above code without getting the error message? Or what is causing the error message to happen for me, but not others?**

As well, here is a brief **reproducible example of the data:**

```
structure(list(GEOID = c("06083002013", "06083002013", "06083002013", 
"06083002011", "06083002011", "06083002011", "06061020711", "06061020711", 
"06061020711", "06061020712", "06061020712", "06061020712", "06061020805", 
"06061020805", "06061020805", "06061020713", "06061020713", "06061020713", 
"06083002502", "06083002502", "06083002502", "06061020715", "06061020715", 
"06061020715", "06061020714"), variable = c("white", "black", 
"hispanic", "white", "black", "hispanic", "white", "black", "hispanic", 
"white", "black", "hispanic", "white", "black", "hispanic", "white", 
"black", "hispanic", "white", "black", "hispanic", "white", "black", 
"hispanic", "white"), estimate = c(2291, 0, 471, 1875, 30, 2720, 
3339, 117, 471, 2628, 9, 809, 2887, 11, 571, 2679, 5, 610, 757, 
57, 6169, 2532, 20, 223, 3132), moe = c(331, 13, 246, 262, 33, 
384, 420, 146, 160, 338, 19, 357, 437, 17, 280, 382, 11, 391, 
232, 50, 382, 309, 30, 149, 438), urban_name = c("Santa Maria", 
"Santa Maria", "Santa Maria", "Santa Maria", "Santa Maria", "Santa Maria", 
"Roseville", "Roseville", "Roseville", "Roseville", "Roseville", 
"Roseville", "Roseville", "Roseville", "Roseville", "Roseville", 
"Roseville", "Roseville", "Santa Maria", "Santa Maria", "Santa Maria", 
"Roseville", "Roseville", "Roseville", "Roseville")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", 
"73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "115", "116", "117", "127", 
"128", "129", "130"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You'll need to update to R 4.1; the formula notation is available for `split()` in 4.1 and higher.

Comment: Thanks, Kyle. Guess this forces me to finally update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code showed, the `split` is a `base R` function which can extract the column with `$` or `[[` or use `with`.  As 'Inglewood' is not showed in the `dput` data, we use `"Roseville"`

```
library(dplyr)
ca_city_data %>%
  filter(urban_name == "Roseville") %>%
  split(.$GEOID)
```

-output

```
$`06061020711`
         GEOID variable estimate moe urban_name
34 06061020711    white     3339 420  Roseville
35 06061020711    black      117 146  Roseville
36 06061020711 hispanic      471 160  Roseville

$`06061020712`
         GEOID variable estimate moe urban_name
37 06061020712    white     2628 338  Roseville
38 06061020712    black        9  19  Roseville
39 06061020712 hispanic      809 357  Roseville

$`06061020713`
         GEOID variable estimate moe urban_name
76 06061020713    white     2679 382  Roseville
77 06061020713    black        5  11  Roseville
78 06061020713 hispanic      610 391  Roseville

$`06061020714`
          GEOID variable estimate moe urban_name
130 06061020714    white     3132 438  Roseville

$`06061020715`
          GEOID variable estimate moe urban_name
127 06061020715    white     2532 309  Roseville
128 06061020715    black       20  30  Roseville
129 06061020715 hispanic      223 149  Roseville

$`06061020805`
         GEOID variable estimate moe urban_name
73 06061020805    white     2887 437  Roseville
74 06061020805    black       11  17  Roseville
75 06061020805 hispanic      571 280  Roseville
```

---

Using the full code

```
 ca_city_data %>%
  filter(urban_name == "Roseville") %>%
  split(.$GEOID) %>% map_dbl(~{
    entropy(
      data = .x,
      group = "variable",
      weight = "estimate",
      base = 4
    )
  }) %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "GEOID") %>% 
  rename(entropy = value)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  GEOID       entropy
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 06061020711   0.358
2 06061020712   0.406
3 06061020713   0.354
4 06061020714   0    
5 06061020715   0.232
6 06061020805   0.338
```

---

It may be also done with `nest_by`

```
ca_city_data %>%
    nest_by(urban_name, GEOID) %>%
    transmute(out = entropy(data = data, group = "variable",
    weight = "estimate", base = 4)) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  urban_name  GEOID         out
  <chr>       <chr>       <dbl>
1 Roseville   06061020711 0.358
2 Roseville   06061020712 0.406
3 Roseville   06061020713 0.354
4 Roseville   06061020714 0    
5 Roseville   06061020715 0.232
6 Roseville   06061020805 0.338
7 Santa Maria 06083002011 0.513
8 Santa Maria 06083002013 0.329
9 Santa Maria 06083002502 0.281
```